# Are these questions about the United Methodist Church too broad or too narrow?

Tags: discussion

Currently, I am practicing in making ***good questions***. Let me see if these questions are ok to be asked on the SE.

> According to the United Methodist Church, by what mechanism is a person ***saved***?
>
> With what denomination(s) does the United Methodist Church's opinion of the method of achieving "***salvation***" concur? (I think this question can also be expressed, "How many denominations share this method of salvation, that ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**?")
>
> How do United Methodist Church members observe Easter? Do they really observe it by eating ham, or is that a familial phenomenon that is not endorsed by the church?

Comment: I think the second would end up closed as a list question; it might be worth a try, then if closed rewrite it to compare to a single denomination.

Answer (score 2):

Id say they're all good.

The salvation question in particular affords space to talk about Arminianism (and any answer that doesn't include it or the words free will is really substandard!) and it's opposition to election. FYI: Methodists are slightly minority, but by no means off the reservation, so asking about the relative prominence of the two is good as well.

The ham question is funny, and gets to the heart of practice- id keep it!